# Buddhist Book Exchange

Tags: discussion

Trying to create a list of people / organisations which distribute Buddhist books for free.

If you distribute please add them as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have known about this non-profit, which is supported by donation:

http://www.budaedu.org/en/book/

Comment: +1 (I found one of their books at a temple in Canada)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Sri Lanka and want any Buddhist publication (**strictly free of charge**) please get in touch with me on:

> **`+94-(0)11-5864614`**

Answer (score 0):

I have found these 48 free books by Mahasi Sayadaw:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zhym9oUSGU

And 33 more free books my Mahasi Sayadaw:

http://www.yellowrobe.com/books/mahasi-sayadaw/237-books-by-mahasi-sayadaw.html

Also here is "What buddhists believe" by Ven. Sri. Dhammananda:

http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/whatbelieve.pdf

And "What the Buddha taught" by Dr. Walpola Rahula:

http://www.dhammaweb.net/books/Dr_Walpola_Rahula_What_the_Buddha_Taught.pdf

And "Visuddhimagga - The Path of Purification":

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf

And "The illustrated Dhammapada":

http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/dhammapadatxt1.pdf

And in short form:

http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books14/Sarada_Maha_Thero-The_Illustrated_Dhammapada.pdf

May all beings be happy, peace and free from suffering.

Harshani